# Build a string in an sql table and insert into another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Say I have a table `Name_Address` as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Name_Address](
[First_Name] [nvarchar] (50)  NULL,
[Last_Name] [nvarchar] (50)  NULL,
[Address] [nvarchar] (50)  NULL,
[City] [nvarchar] (50)  NULL,
[State] [nvarchar] (50)  NULL,
[Zip] [nvarchar] (50)  NULL,
[Phone] [nvarchar] (50)  NULL,
[Cell] [nvarchar] (50)  NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Is there a way in SQL that I can build a string:

```
<First Name>John<Last Name>Smith<Address>1233 Your Street<City>Home Town<State>NY<Zip>123456-1234<Phone>111-111-1111<Cell>222-222-222
```

and insert it into another table?

Original post did not show the xml tags as part of the desired result: without code formatting the tags were interpreted literally and were not displayed.

Answer (score 3):

You would just use the `+` to concatenate the values together.

```
INSERT INTO yourNewTable (newRecord)
SELECT First_Name + Last_Name + Address + City + State + Zip + Phone + Cell
FROM dbo.Name_Address
```

Or add spaces:

```
INSERT INTO yourNewTable (newRecord)
SELECT First_Name + ' ' + Last_Name + ' ' 
 + Address + ' ' + City + ' ' + State + ' ' + Zip 
 + Phone + ' ' + Cell
FROM dbo.Name_Address
```

You can also use `FOR XML PATH` if you want this in XML format:

```
select *
from name_address
for xml path
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/265d3/2)

Or you can hand-code the XML tags, if you want to insert the full record into another table you can use:

```
insert into yourNewTable (yourNewRecord)
select '<FirstName>'+[First_Name] 
  + '<Last_Name>'+[Last_Name] 
  +'<Address>'+[Address] 
  +'<City>'+[City] 
  +'<State>'+[State] 
  +'<Zip>'+[Zip] 
  +'<Phone>'+[Phone] 
  +'<Cell>'+[Cell]
from name_address
```

## see [Sql Fiddle with Select Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/265d3/5)

Comment: add some ' ' spaces and you will get a nicer result :)

Comment: @Randy I would add spaces, but the original request did not have spaces.

Comment: hmm.. i see that there are some XML looking tags there as well.. maybe thats what the OP is after.. in any case - those are literals.

Comment: @Randy the XML tags were not present when I initially answered. I updated my answer to include a `FOR XML PATH` query

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate fields together using ||:

```
select First_name||' '||Last_Name||' '+Address . . .
from NameAddress
```

To insert into another table, you can do something like:

```
insert into AnotherTable
    select '<First Name>'||First_name||'<Last Name>'||Last_Name||'<Address>'+Address . . .
    from NameAddress
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   INSERT INTO MyTable(MyString) 
   SELECT
    '<FirstName>'+[First_Name] + '<Last_Name>'+[Last_Name] +'<Address>'+[Address] +<City>+[City] +<State>+[State] +'<Zip>'+[Zip] +'<Phone>'+[Phone] +'<Cell>'+[Cell] 

    FROM [dbo].[Name_Address]
```

Comment: That will work to create a new table, but won't work if the target table already exists.

Comment: Yes, I edited and removed the 'INTO #TMP' and added the 'INSERT INTO MyTable(MyString) '. We should drop #TMP at the end of the query. Thx